# How can I check if I exit back to the ps terminal?

Tags: linux, windows, console, user-controls, wsl-2

The question may sound a bit strange.

The situation is as following:

- I execute the command "wsl" in the powershell console. My default
  distro starts or get restored.
- I execute some commands, if I need root rights, I switch to "sudo
  -i". Then I exit and get back to previous user. If I exit one time more (maybe accidently) I return back to powershell environment. Or I
  even exit accidently the console completely. This behaviour I don't
  like, but this isn't the point.

Now I want to somehow record when I leave the last session in Linux. I tried it the other way around by adding a command in *wsl.conf*:

```
command=touch /tmp/test.xyz
```

Unfortunately, that doesn't help, as the command apparently only runs once after "*wsl --shutdown*" (at least I think so).
My idea was to remove the temp file after my script is done with it; to use it like a switch.

Now my new idea is to use a "bash_logout" script. But I have no idea how I could check if the current user is the first (or last if I exit the current).
Commands like

```
w
who
users
```

seems only show the current user not any "inherits".

And something like

```
exit & su
```

Seems not to be working.

#### So how can I check if my current console session would be the last if I would exit it?

Maybe I'm missing something obvious, if so, I'm sorry. I try to get better with linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a programmatic way of checking try examining the output from the following:

`echo -e "User: $USER\nSUDO_USER: $SUDO_USER\nLOGNAME: $LOGNAME\nlogname: $(logname)"`

Start with your own user, then change around via sudo and su etc., depending on the Linux distro, sudo version, and potentially the shell (bash, zsh, etc.) you may get different results then I do. I've also observed **SUDO_USER** not get populated on some older server distributions.

---

On a fairly recent distribution this produced:

If **thedude** logs in as the first user: the **SUDO_USER** environment variable is empty; both **USER** and **LOGNAME** environment variables have a value of `thedude`;  `logname` command output is `thedude`:

```
User: thedude
SUDO_USER: 
LOGNAME: thedude
logname: thedude
```

If **thedude** then uses `sudo -i` to change to **root**:

```
User: root
SUDO_USER: thedude
LOGNAME: root
logname: thedude
```

Then from **root** uses `su walter` to become **walter**:

```
User: walter
SUDO_USER: thedude
LOGNAME: walter
logname: thedude
```

but if it was instead of `su walter` it was `sudo su walter` to become **walter**, stacking a second `sudo` command **SUDO_USER** gets overwritten with `root`, but `logname` still has a value of `thedude`, showing it is the first login:

```
User: walter
SUDO_USER: root
LOGNAME: walter
logname: thedude
```

---

I use the etckeeper project with `.bash_logout` to force a commit any time `/etc` has been altered with the commit message of:

```
Session exit commit:
* User: $USER
* SUDO_USER: $SUDO_USER
* LOGNAME: $LOGNAME
* logname: $(logname)
```

but for you, this could be a comparison like:

```
if [[ "${USER}" = "${LOGNAME}" ]] && [[ "${USER}" = "$(logname)" ]]; then
    # First user and last to logout of host. Do something.
    touch /tmp/test.xyz
fi
```

Comment: $LOGNAME seems to work. I'm not sure about uppercase lowercase and the if comparison. I'll try this out more closely. Maybe I have further questions.

Comment: After extensive investigation, I'm wondering how you managed to get $logname (/bin/logname) to produce output? After a pretty stupid hack (sudo logname) I managed it too.
During my research I came across this post:
https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/3085
Otherwise, I am very satisfied. It took quite a bit of effort, including using "bash_rc.local" and ditching "/tmp" in favor of something permanent. Unfortunately, otherwise no output is generated if you close the ps terminal with the x.